# Get value of listbox item with item template

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, itemtemplate

I have a window with a property called `IpList` of type `ObervableCollection<string>` and I set the window's `DataContext` property to the window itself so that I can bind properties from XAML elements to properties of the window. One XAML element in my window is a `ListBox` that has an `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListBox
    ItemsSource="{Binding IpList}"
    x:Name="lbIps">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <Button
                    Click="lbIps_bnClose_Click"
                    Content="X"
                    DockPanel.Dock="Left" />
                <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I want the list box items to remove themselves when their "X" button is clicked. My first attempt was to obtain the selected item index and remove this from the list. But when I only click on the button, no item is selected. My second attempt was to remove the item by value instead of index, but I couldn't figure out how to obtain the value of the list box item containing the clicked button. So my questions are: **Is there a possibility to obtain the index/value of the list box item containing the clicked button? If so, how can I do this? Is there another way to remove the parent list box item of a clicked "X" button?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void lbIps_bnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var vm = this.DataContext as [yourViewModelName];

   var button = sender as Button;

   var item = (string)button.DataContext;

   vm.IpList.Remove(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using MVVM:

Put this in the click event

```
string s=(string)((sender as Button).DataContext);
IpList.Remove(item);
```

Comment: I didn't understand `string s=Button btn=...`, but I understood what you've meant and it works. Thank you :)

Comment: @Cubinator73 No, that was a Typo, sorry. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Indeed there was this very little mistake, but I didn't downvote this answer. I upvoted it, because I understood what you wanted to say. :)